Conan2 : Loading environment variables from bash script in Cmake
In Conan2, there are new autogenerated files that contains useful variables like the package location.
In macOS, the file is called conanbuild.sh which calls a more specific file named conanbuildenv-debug-armv8.sh which export the desired environment file:
For example: the contents of conanbuild.sh:
. "/Users/user/cmake-proj/conanbuildenv-debug-armv8.sh"

and for file conanbuildenv-debug-armv8.sh:
export CONAN_PKG_ROOT="$CONAN_PKG_ROOT /Users/user/.conan2/p/blablabla/p"

Now I want to be able to use the variable CONAN_PKG_ROOT from CMakeLists.txt.
My current workaround to get this variable on CMakeLists.txt is very complicated and involve creating a temporal file called tmp.sh that echo the value as stdout, and reading it as RESULT_VARIABLE from cmake execute_process.
execute_process(COMMAND bash "-c" "source ./conanbuild.sh; echo -n 'echo $CONAN_PKG_ROOT' > tmp.sh; bash ./tmp.sh; rm ./tmp.sh"
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
                RESULT_VARIABLE variable_RESULT
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE variable_OUTPUT
)

message("${variable_OUTPUT}")

I'm sure there's an easier way to get this variable in CMake file which doesn't change the contents of the auto-generated files. Perhaps anybody knows how?

Normally, scripts which setup environment are run before cmake. You may create a wrapper for cmake, which firstly executes your conanbuild.sh script and only then executes cmake.

@Tsyvarev, but than I need the wrapper to be cross-platform like python script ? but are there more native CMake solutions ?

On every machine, where you want to build your CMake project, you may create its own wrapper. E.g. if on some machine you want to install dependencies via Conan, you may create a wrapper which runs conan-specific scripts. On a machine which installs dependencies via vcpkg, you may create a wrapper which runs vcpkg-specific scripts.

@Tsyvarev, my goal is to install dependencies via Conan which are used by my project during compile time.  what do you mean by create a wrapper which runs conan-specific scripts. ? do you mean that I create some kind of python script that calls the auto-generated scripts Conan created for me ? Perhaps you can point me to an example please ? thanks !

Example of wrapper script (line by line): #!/bin/sh, /path/to/conanbuild.sh, cmake "$@". You may save this script into the file conan-cmake and run it as a regular CMake: conan-cmake -S <source-dir> -B <binary-dir> <other args>.

@Tsyvarev, the wrapper script method is indeed working. However, my CMake is recursive, so when I call cmake -S . I calls the CMakeLists.txt from the sub-folders using add_subdirectory method. can I replace my script with the CMakeLists.txt file so I can call it using the same method ?

Whatever process is started by the "main" CMake process, it inherits all environment variables by default. So if your use a wrapper for the root project, then all subproject will receive the variable CONAN_PKG_ROOT.

You can use an environment variable from Cmake (be sure it's exported) using this syntax
set(MyVar "$ENV{MY_VAR}")

check https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html

Hi, unfortunately I get an empty string meaning that the variable is undefined. for some reason, the exported variable, isn't shown on the CMake environment. Perhaps you can try it using my minimal reproducible example.
